# Use optim to find longest date range

Tags: r

I'm attempting to learn to use optim but failing here. I cannot seem to get my head around how to make the call to optim correctly. Thanks in advance for your help.

The following code looks at SPY and using the function FindRange determines dates that cover the first & last crossings of TestLevel==100. As I want to optimize I created a wrapper function OptimFindRange that returns the number of days from start to finish as the scalar I want to maximize. There are some simple loops to test that things work more or less correctly. (I think they do...)

I am completely lost, however, in how to use optim to do this. I clearly don't understand how to set up the call, most specifically the par input vs my data & level values. Help!

```
library(quantmod)

FindRange = function(d1, level){
  if (level == 0){ #To bypass search)
    DS = first(index(d1))
    DE = last(index(d1))
  }else{
    DS = index(first(d1[(Cl(d1)>level) & lag(Cl(d1)<level)]))
    DE = index( last(d1[(Cl(d1)>level) & lag(Cl(d1)<level)]))
  }
  return(c(DS,DE))
}

#Optimizable call to FindRange that
#returns a scalar
OptimFindRange = function(data, level){
  RetVal = FindRange(data, level)
  Result1 = as.integer(RetVal[2]-RetVal[1])
  return(Result1)
}

TestSym = "SPY"
Source = "yahoo"
StartDate = "1990-01-01"
Adjust = TRUE
TestLevel = 100

getSymbols(TestSym,src=Source,from=StartDate,adjust=Adjust)

data = get(TestSym)
#Plot all data and TestLevel
plot(Cl(data),main=TestSym)
abline(h=TestLevel, col="black", lty=1)

#Simple test to get start & end dates for TestLevel
R1 = FindRange(data, TestLevel)

InitDate  = R1[1]
FinalDate = R1[2]
NumDays = as.integer(R1[2] - R1[2])

TestData = data[ (index(data)>=InitDate) & (index(data)<=FinalDate) ]
#Plot only range of data with TestValue
plot(Cl(TestData),main=TestSym)
abline(h=TestLevel, col="black", lty=1)


#Test only
#Call OptimFindRange function in loop
xl = ceiling(min(Cl(data)))
xu = floor(max(Cl(data)))
Vec1 = vector()
for (i in xl:xu){
  tmp1 = OptimFindRange(data, i)
  print(paste("TestLevel:",i," - Num days: ",as.integer(tmp1)))
  Vec1[i] = as.integer(tmp1)
  rm(tmp1)
}
LongestLevel = order(Vec1, decreasing=TRUE)[1]
#Get date range
FindRange(data, LongestLevel)
#End test


#Limits for optimization?
MaxLevel = max(Cl(TestData))
MinLevel = min(Cl(TestData))

#Trying to optimze but I don't understand
optim(fn=OptimFindRange, data = TestData, 
      level = ave(MaxLevel,MinLevel),
      method="Brent", 
      lower=MinLevel, upper=MaxLevel,
      control=list(fnscale=-1)
)
```

Comment: This is not a good use of the `optim` function. The `optim` function assumes you have a smooth function one really works best when your function is unimodal. When you print out the test values for each level, you see that your function goes up and down and it's difficult to predict given any two values in which direction the optimum exists. Because you have irregular discrete data, you really will need to calculate the value for each point to find the maximum.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not a good application of optim and likely optim will fail. Thanks